# Arbitary Length lookups in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have, for example, a table that gives correspondence between teams and their leaders:

| Team | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | Alex |
| Bravo | Alice |
| Charlie | Andy |
| Dealta | Ali |
| HMP Liverpool | Ally |

In another table I want to do the following:

| Staff member | Previous Teams | Possible references |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Billy | Alpha | Alex |
| Becky | Alpha, Bravo | Alex, Alice |
| Barry | Charlie, Delta | Andy, Ali |

And have a formula that automatically works out the 'possible references' column, given any number of valid entries in the 'Previous Teams' column. Is this possible in Excel without resorting to VBA?

Comment: A bit of a sample of some of the anticipated results might help. I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are looking for.

Comment: Also complete source data, and an explanation of the relationship between both tables. Ex.: where does Billy come from in the second table? Is the first table a list of previous team managers or current ones? etc..

Comment: @BradR sorry, the last column in the second table *is* the anticipated results.

Answer (score 0):

If one has `TEXTJOIN()` you could do the following:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),A$2:B$6,2,0))
```

Depending on your version of Excel you may have to CSE-enter this.

Comment: Hmmm - I have textjoin - but I get '#NAME?' error even if I CSE it... Version 16.16... any

Comment: `FILTERXML()` is windows only (and not online either). Do you have MAC by any chance? @Joe

Comment: I do! Well that *is* interesting. I suspect that technically answers the question then, even if I shoudl have specified the question a better more tightly!